# Как задать Background элементу XAML используя system.drawing.Color.FromRgb?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть новый цвет

```
NewColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(R, G, B);
```

Есть элемент с именем

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1"></Grid>
```

Как преобразовать NewColor для присвоения цвета элементу?

```
Grid1.Backgound = NewColor............
```

Comment: У вас не тот неймспейс. Вам нужны Color/ColorConverter из `System.Windows.Media`

Comment: В WPF, с его XAML, вы не должны хотеть в коде устанавливать цвета, стили, и прочее. Научитесь грамотно использовать имеющиеся у вас возможности. В нормальном проекте, у вас не должно быть вообще `x:Name`, должно быть разделение всего на мало связанные друг с другом слои. Вот например, хотите вы установить цвет, ок, на основе чего он должен браться? Предположим, что условное состояние "активен или нет", вот делаете в C# простое `bool` свойство, а в XAML делаете триггер, который привязываете к этому свойству, ну а внутри триггера задаете цвет нужному элементу, все, в C# у вас нет цвета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NewColor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);

new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(NewColor.ToString()));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]